# Increment a number from nil to 1 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following piece of code which works really well for incrementing a number based on the latest maximum number in the database. However, if this is nil, I get an error.

What I'd like to achieve is that I can keep the `share_number: @latest_share += 1` in place but also check on this line that if that returns nil that we set it nil to 1, and then the loop continues.

Is this possible somehow?

Thanks!

```
# Get last sharenumber in captable 
@latest_share = @transaction.captable.shares.maximum(:share_number)

@number_of_share_numbers_to_create.times do |i| # TODO Refactor this so we don't slow down the application with so many queries
  Share.create(
    owner_id: params[:buying_shareholder_id], 
    captable_id: @transaction.captable.id, 
    company_id: @transaction.company.id, 
    share_number: @latest_share += 1 #Increment up from the latest number, but start at 1 if this is nil 
  )
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd simply change

```
@latest_share = @transaction.captable.shares.maximum(:share_number)
```

to

```
@latest_share = @transaction.captable.shares.maximum(:share_number) || 0
```

or alternatively (assuming that you're operating on integers)

```
@latest_share = @transaction.captable.shares.maximum(:share_number).to_i
```

as `nil.to_i == 0`

Comment: Went with this `@latest_share = @transaction.captable.shares.maximum(:share_number) || 0`. Worked great, thanks!